# Xaml copy text from datagridtemplatecolumn

Tags: xaml

I have following code:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="Auto" Header="Čas registrace" SortMemberPath="ECreationTime">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" >
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Focusable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding Path=ECreationTime,StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Focusable="True" Width="10"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Focusable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Crimson" Text="{Binding Path=ECreationTime,StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm:ss\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have more columns inside datagrid. When someone want to copy full row - its ok, but only this particular column isnt possible to copy. I think it is due to stack panels and multiple textboxes. But i need to keep them that way. Because of formatting and colors. Any ideas how to solve this? I really want to copy also from this column. Thanks.

Comment: Why is every text box within its own stack panel?

Comment: Because i want the textboxes adjacent. Not every textboxes under themselves.

Comment: Ok, was a question aside, let me write my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think you should implement your own Copying, look the following example:

Template

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" ClipboardCopyMode="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CopyCommand" />
    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Command="Copy" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FullName" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CodeBehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
    private void CopyCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var person = DataGrid.SelectedItem as Person;
        Clipboard.SetText($"{person.Id}\t{person.FirstName}\t{person.LastName}\t{person.Age}");
    }
}
```

This is a very simple when you target accept plain text, if not you should try to use other clipboard methods and accomodate to your target data formats (JSON, XML, Binary, Html)

Comment: Its working. I do it simillar way in my MVVM pattern and its great. Thanks a lot :)